# Unable to "List channel messages" on Azure AD Graph API Beta

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, http-get, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When I try to list channel messages I get:

```
[...] "code": "UnknownError", "message": "Failed to execute backend request." [...]
```

This error is for all teams I don't belong to.

I have this error when trying to call the API from Microsoft Flow (with HTTP GET) but also with Graph Explorer: the account I used has FULL permission but still asks to check my permission:

```
Failure - Status Code 403, 656ms Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions
```

And the registered application has the delegated permission needed to call this endpoint regarding the documentation:

`GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta

Is it a bug because of the "beta" or something I've missed?

Comment: Are you getting the same error from Graph Explorer? Can you click on modify permissions (left pane) and see if you have granted Group.ReadWrite.All permission?

Comment: Yes on Graph Explorer i got : Failure - Status Code 403, 705ms Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions

+ i have granted Group.ReadWrite.All permission

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRZ52.png

Comment: BTW : I don't get any issue to call "Get Channel Info"

Comment: Can you try [Create Team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta) once?

Comment: It works without any error in Graph Explorer with :

{
  "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates/standard",
  "displayName": "HNS-call-create-teams",
  "description": "My Sample Team’s from Graph Explorer",
}

but i notice there is a difference between those 2 endpoints 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta accepte Application Permission when https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta only support delegated permission is it something important in this case ?

Comment: Could you please share your tenant id? Also, please provide the request id for your request which you can find in Response Headers.

Comment: Thx for your time, is it possible to send you those informations in "private" ?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT it seems i'm not able to "chat" with you for the moment because account is new. is it possible to send you all those information through an other way please ?

Comment: Here is developer support alias: 
microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

Comment: Thx, i sent you all details with 2 samples . Thx for your help

Comment: I am running into this same issue. My API call can get the team, channel, and individual messages if I have the ID, but cannot list messages in a channel, My user/token has delegated perms and is in the team/channel .....I get {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'messages'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1d3b4d6b-3355-4ccf-9877-d7ca2898d701",
            "date": "2019-02-20T17:13:01"
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

After searching and testing I can confirm that I was miss understanding how the delegated permission works.

The user need to have the permission to read the chat message meaning that the user need to be at least a member of the team who is concerned by the call.

I confirmed it by testing on a teams/groups where the account is not member of (result = Satus code 403) and everything is working with success after adding the account in the teams/groups

**Does this mean that at the moment to be able to List channel messages from all teams in organisation we need to have a unique account member of each teams (=account used in the microsoft-graph call) ?**

if anyone faced same situation this video helps to understand more easly the concept : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPkHvy3eRCM